# Ubuntu 12.04 /usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lGL

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ati, amd-processor

I istalled the fglrx ATI/AMD proprietary driver and now when i try to launch my OpenGL/SDL project i receive this message: **/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lGL**

I run Ubuntu 12.04 desktop, 64-bit. HD6870 [ATI Radeon HD 6800 Series]

Comment: I unistall the ati driver and now i have the same error with the open driver, so i try to reinstall the ati driver and also the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing `fglrx-glx` should help you, those are libGL's for proprietary AMD/ATI drivers.

Comment: I tryed, but i have the same problem. Other ideas?

Comment: You compile that project yourself from source or is it a binary from somewhere else? if 1) - try recompiling after installing that package, if 2, can you show the output of `ldd </path/to/binary>`?

Comment: i compile it from my source and i tryed to compile it after installing fglrx-glx