# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt-creator

I have installed qt and when I run application on qt I get this error.

```
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 make: *** [test3] Error 1
 14:05:48: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
```

I think this error is related to OpenGL.
I have run all these commands but nothing happened

```
 sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
 sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev
```

My pro file is :

```
  #-------------------------------------------------
  #
  # Project created by QtCreator 2015-05-19T17:40:19
  #
  #-------------------------------------------------

  QT       += core gui

   greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

  TARGET = test19
  TEMPLATE = app

   SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

   HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

   FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Comment: Run `ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so`. If it contains `libGL.so` - restart QtCreator.

Comment: Are you following http://wiki.qt.io/Building-Qt-5-from-Git? That usually gets the job done for me when I'm setting up a Linux machine.

Comment: terminal shows me this when i run command                              libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.4.20) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
 libGL.so.1 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 2.4.20) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1  I have closed qt creator and  then run it again but got the same error   @Amartel

Answer (score 1):

> terminal shows me this when i run command
>
> libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.4.20) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
> libGL.so.1 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 2.4.20) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1

Proper links where not created while installing needed packages. I don't know why, but here is how you can fix this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: Does `ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so` shows all 4 libs now?

Comment: libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.4.20) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
 libGL.so.1 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 2.4.20) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
 libGL.so (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.4.20) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
 libGL.so (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 2.4.20) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so   yup @ Amartel

Comment: Restart (just in case), open a terminal and run these commands: `cd /tmp`, `echo "int main() {return 0;}" > main.cpp`, `gcc -lGL -omain main.cpp`. If it finishes without errors, then your linker is fine - try to rebuild your project (`Build->Rebuild All`).

Comment: Same error on my example, or on rebuilding project?

Comment: Could you add your 'pro' file to your question.

Comment: I have updated my question by adding pro file   @Amartel

Comment: Try one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558406/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lgl-when-building-a-qt-application or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867913/ubuntu-12-04-usr-bin-ld-error-cannot-find-lgl